# Classpath outside of signed Java application bundle in OS X?

Tags: java, operating-system, classpath, bundle

Does OS X permit a signed application to execute Java class files that are outside of the application bundle?  For years we've distributed a Java application whose class files lie outside the executable bundle -- so that modules can be found and loaded dynamically -- using the bundle's Info.plist file to specify the external classpath (as $APP_PACKAGE/../).  Before starting the apparently-arduous journey to getting the app signed, I wanted to see if such an arrangement was even permitted in the modern security-conscious world.